# How to share large files between .NET and android

Tags: java, android, .net, tcp, file-sharing

I have built a simple app in C#.net which shares large files within PC's folder. E.g. from one folder to another using TCP/IP Protocol. 
But I want to do this in PC to Android device using TCP/IP protocol.
I am new to java but have some experience in .NET.

Here is the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LargeFile
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void bt_send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dlg_open_file.ShowDialog() ==System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                String selected_file = dlg_open_file.FileName;
                String file_name = Path.GetFileName(selected_file);
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(selected_file, FileMode.Open);
                TcpClient tc = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 6868);
                NetworkStream ns = tc.GetStream();
                byte[] data_tosend = CreateDataPacket(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("125"), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file_name));
                ns.Write(data_tosend, 0, data_tosend.Length);
                ns.Flush();
                Boolean loop_break = false;
                while (true)
                {
                    if (ns.ReadByte() == 2)
                    {
                        byte[] cmd_buff = new byte[3];
                        ns.Read(cmd_buff, 0, cmd_buff.Length);
                        byte[] recv_data = ReadStream(ns);
                        switch (Convert.ToInt32(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(cmd_buff)))
                        {
                            case 126:
                                long recv_file_pointer = long.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recv_data));
                                if (recv_file_pointer != fs.Length)
                                {
                                    fs.Seek(recv_file_pointer,SeekOrigin.Begin);
                                    int temp_buff_length = (int)(fs.Length - recv_file_pointer < 20000 ? fs.Length - recv_file_pointer: 20000);
                                    byte[] temp_buff = new byte[temp_buff_length];
                                    fs.Read(temp_buff, 0,temp_buff.Length);
                                    byte[] data_to_send = CreateDataPacket(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("127"), temp_buff);
                                    ns.Write(data_to_send, 0,data_to_send.Length);
                                    ns.Flush();
                                    pb_upload.Value = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)recv_file_pointer / (double)fs.Length * 100);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    byte[] data_to_send = CreateDataPacket(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("128"),Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Close"));
                                    ns.Write(data_to_send, 0,data_to_send.Length);
                                    ns.Flush();
                                    fs.Close();
                                    loop_break = true;
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (loop_break == true)
                    {
                        ns.Close();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public byte[] ReadStream(NetworkStream ns)
        {
            byte[] data_buff = null;

            int b = 0;
            String buff_length = "";
            while ((b = ns.ReadByte()) != 4)
            {
                buff_length += (char)b;
            }
            int data_length = Convert.ToInt32(buff_length);
            data_buff = new byte[data_length];
            int byte_read = 0;
            int byte_offset = 0;
            while (byte_offset < data_length)
            {
                byte_read = ns.Read(data_buff, byte_offset,data_length - byte_offset);
                byte_offset += byte_read;
            }

            return data_buff;
        }
        private byte[] CreateDataPacket(byte[] cmd, byte[] data)
        {
            byte[] initialize = new byte[1];
            initialize[0] = 2;
            byte[] separator = new byte[1];
            separator[0] = 4;
            byte[] datalength = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(data.Length));
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            ms.Write(initialize, 0, initialize.Length);
            ms.Write(cmd, 0, cmd.Length);
            ms.Write(datalength, 0, datalength.Length);
            ms.Write(separator, 0, separator.Length);
            ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }


        private void bt_start_server_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TCPServer obj_server = new TCPServer();
            System.Threading.Thread obj_thread = new

            System.Threading.Thread(obj_server.StartServer);
            obj_thread.Start();
        }



        class TCPServer
        {
            TcpListener obj_server;
            public TCPServer()
            {
                obj_server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 6868);
            }

            public void StartServer()
            {
                obj_server.Start();
                while (true)
                {
                    TcpClient tc = obj_server.AcceptTcpClient();
                    SocketHandler obj_handler = new SocketHandler(tc);
                    System.Threading.Thread obj_thread = new System.Threading.Thread(obj_handler.ProcessSocketRequest);
                    obj_thread.Start();
                }
            }

            class SocketHandler
            {
                NetworkStream ns;
                public SocketHandler(TcpClient tc)
                {
                    ns = tc.GetStream();
                }

                public void ProcessSocketRequest()
                {
                    FileStream fs = null;
                    long current_file_pointer = 0;
                    Boolean loop_break = false;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (ns.ReadByte() == 2)
                        {
                            byte[] cmd_buff = new byte[3];
                            ns.Read(cmd_buff, 0, cmd_buff.Length);
                            byte[] recv_data = ReadStream();
                            switch (Convert.ToInt32(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(cmd_buff)))
                            {
                                case 125:
                                    {
                                        fs = new FileStream(@"C:\tl\" + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recv_data), FileMode.CreateNew);
                                        byte[] data_to_send = CreateDataPacket(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("126"),


                                            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(current_file_pointer)));
                                        ns.Write(data_to_send, 0,data_to_send.Length);
                                        ns.Flush();
                                    }
                                    break;

                                case 127:
                                    {
                                        fs.Seek(current_file_pointer,SeekOrigin.Begin);
                                        fs.Write(recv_data, 0,recv_data.Length);
                                        current_file_pointer = fs.Position;
                                        byte[] data_to_send = CreateDataPacket(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("126"),


                                            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(current_file_pointer)));
                                        ns.Write(data_to_send, 0,data_to_send.Length);
                                        ns.Flush();
                                    }
                                    break;

                                case 128:
                                    {
                                        fs.Close();
                                        loop_break = true;
                                    }
                                    break;

                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (loop_break == true)
                        {
                            ns.Close();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                public byte[] ReadStream()
                {
                    byte[] data_buff = null;

                    int b = 0;
                    String buff_length = "";
                    while ((b = ns.ReadByte()) != 4)
                    {
                        buff_length += (char)b;
                    }
                    int data_length = Convert.ToInt32(buff_length);
                    data_buff = new byte[data_length];
                    int byte_read = 0;
                    int byte_offset = 0;
                    while (byte_offset < data_length)
                    {
                        byte_read = ns.Read(data_buff, byte_offset,data_length - byte_offset);
                        byte_offset += byte_read;
                    }

                    return data_buff;
                }

                private byte[] CreateDataPacket(byte[] cmd, byte[] data)
                {
                    byte[] initialize = new byte[1];
                    initialize[0] = 2;
                    byte[] separator = new byte[1];
                    separator[0] = 4;
                    byte[] datalength = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(data.Length));
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    ms.Write(initialize, 0, initialize.Length);
                    ms.Write(cmd, 0, cmd.Length);
                    ms.Write(datalength, 0, datalength.Length);
                    ms.Write(separator, 0, separator.Length);
                    ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    return ms.ToArray();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I believe that Class "TCPserver" is resposible for receiving the data.

So can anybody help me or guide me how to do this in android.

I have successfully sent the message from Android to PC. I have also sent some text string from java desktop app to .net desktop app, that was easy. 
But stuck here.

My Main task is to send the video file from PC to device and play it on the device.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.
Let me know if someone needs more information.
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can use SMB or NFS? both of them need a server app that can support these protocol. what is you Client and what is your Server?

Comment: @EliadCohen I want to send file from PC so i think it's server and i want to receive it in Android device and it's client.

Comment: @donggas90 Help me here please!

Comment: if you want to send from the pc so the pc is the Client side, and the Android is the server side, maybe you just need to build a client/server app and install it in the pc and in the Android

Comment: Yeah. But i need to code this functionality in another app :(

Comment: From my knowledge, and i'm not an Android expert, you have to run an application in the Android side